# The new session command returned a value ('Unknown error') that is not a valid JSON object

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, request, microsoft-edge

#### Problem

When I try to run the application in the IDE (**Jetbrains Rider**) an error occurs:

```
[16:17:44.394] - Listening on http://127.0.0.1:44823/ [16:17:44.394] - Listening on http://[::1]:44823/ Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The new session command returned a value ('Unknown error') that is not a valid JSON object.    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeOptions options)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor()    at WebRequest_Login.InstagramSelenium.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Alexx\RiderProjects\WebRequest-Login\WebRequest-Login\Program.cs:line 174
```

---

#### Source Code

```
    IWebDriver  driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com");

    IWebElement usernameInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']"));
    IWebElement passwordInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']"));


    usernameInput.SendKeys("YourUsername");
    passwordInput.SendKeys("YourPassword");
```

---

#### Properties of the NuGet Packages used

`Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver` - Version `87.0.669`

`Selenium.WebDriver` - Version `4.0.0-alpha07`

Comment: I want to confirm with you, whether you are making a test with the Edge legacy browser or you are using the Edge Chromium browser? Please inform us the version of the Edge browser may help us to understand the issue in a better way. If you are using the Edge chromium-browser then you need to add `options.UseChromium = true;` in your code. Here is a sample code [example](https://justpaste.it/94w7m).